# What is the Android Native Development Kit (NDK)?

Tags: android, android-ndk

What is the Android NDK (native development kit) ? How can one use it? Why should one use it?

Comment: Try this link: [What is the NDK?](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Of Android NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068378/use-of-android-ndk)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The NDK (Native Development Kit) is a tool that allows you to program in C/C++ for Android devices. It's intended to integrate with the SDK (it's described as a "companion tool") and used only for performance-critical portions of a project. See [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) for more information.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub - On an Android device, code that's written in Java runs in the Java Virtual Machine, a system-supplied program that interprets Java byte codes. Code that's written in C/C++ is compiled into machine instructions that are run directly by the CPU. This latter code is called "native" code because it is native to the CPU. Note that different CPUs require different native code instructions. Hence, when you use the NDK you have the option of generating code for a single hardware type or for a wide range of CPUs, all of which end up packaged in the .apk file for your application.

Comment: So, if I want to use OpenCV on Android, is it better to use C++ version of it?

Comment: @user8663682 - I'd recommend  using the [Android version](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/). It still requires the use of NDK, but all the work of exposing the capabilities to Android apps has already been done.

Answer (score 59):

NDK may improve application performance. This is usually true for many
processor-bound applications. Many multimedia applications and video games use
native code for processor-intensive tasks.
The performance improvements can come from three sources. Firstly, the native code is compiled to a binary code and run directly on OS, while Java code is translated into Java
byte-code and interpreted by **Dalvik Virtual Machine (VM)**. At Android 2.2 or higher,
a **Just-In-Time (JIT)** compiler is added to Dalvik VM to analyze and optimize the Java
byte-code while the program is running (for example, JIT can compile a part of the
byte-code to binary code before its execution). But in many cases, native code still
runs faster than Java code.

> Java code is run by Dalvik VM on Android. Dalvik VM is specially designed
>   for systems with constrained hardware resources (memory space, processor
>   speed, and so on).

The second source for performance improvements at NDK is that native code allows
developers to make use of some processor features that are not accessible at Android SDK,
such as NEON, a **Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD)** technology, allowing multiple
data elements to be processed in parallel. One particular coding task example is the color
conversion for a video frame or a photo. Suppose we are to convert a photo of 1920x1280
pixels from the RGB color space to the YCbCr color space. The naive approach is to apply a
conversion formula to every pixel (that is, over two million pixels). **With NEON, we can process multiple pixels at one time to reduce the processing time.**

The third aspect is that we can optimize the critical code at an assembly level, which is a
common practice in desktop software development.

**Disadvantage**

NDK cannot access lots of APIs available in the Android SDK directly, and developing in NDK will always introduce extra complexity
into your application.

Answer (score 19):

The Android NDK is a companion tool used only in conjunction with Android SDK which allows application developers to build performance-critical portions of their apps by use of native (C/C++) code.

This provide benefits in form of reuse of existing code and increased speed.

Please go through below links.

[Link-1](http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/10/26/android-ndk-an-introduction-how-to-work-with-ndk/)

[Link-2](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/)

[Link-3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html)

Answer (score 7):

> The **Android NDK** is a companion tool to the **Android SDK** that lets you build performance-critical portions of your apps in native code. It provides headers and *libraries* that allow you to build activities, handle user input, use hardware sensors, access application resources, and more, when programming in **C or C++**. If you write native code, your applications are still packaged into an .apk file and they still run inside of a virtual machine on the device. The fundamental Android application model does not change.

The following links also answers your question:

[What is NDK?](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html)

[When to Develop in Native Code](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#choosing)

[NDK Download](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)

[How to build NDK app](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-build-android-ndk)

[how to work with NDK](http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/10/26/android-ndk-an-introduction-how-to-work-with-ndk/)

[10 tips for Android NDK](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/238-10-android-ndk-tips/)

Answer (score 3):

> The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you embed components that make
>   use of native code in your Android applications.
>
> Android applications run in the Dalvik virtual machine. The NDK allows
>   you to implement parts of your applications using native-code
>   languages such as C and C++. This can provide benefits to certain
>   classes of applications, in the form of reuse of existing code and in
>   some cases increased speed.

Source: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

> The Android NDK is a companion tool to the Android SDK that lets you
>   build performance-critical portions of your apps in native code. It
>   provides headers and libraries that allow you to build activities,
>   handle user input, use hardware sensors, access application resources,
>   and more, when programming in C or C++. If you write native code, your
>   applications are still packaged into an .apk file and they still run
>   inside of a virtual machine on the device. The fundamental Android
>   application model does not change.

Source: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 3):

NDK is just a set of tools which lets you to write C/C++ codes for your application.For example suppose you want to add a critical function/performance to your app and you want to write it in C/C++ then eclipse or any other IDE will not allow you to write your C/C++ and in that case you have to use NDK and integrate it in your app.

Answer (score 2):

NDK is a toolset that allows you to implement parts of your app using native-code languages such as C and C++....Checkout this https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: This detail is already in the accepted answer. How do you think it should be a separate answer?

Comment: Trying to score more I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

> Android NDK (native development kit)

Android Native Development Kit (NDK) is developers to write code in C/C++ that compiles to native code

> Why should one use it?

The source code is compiled directly into machine code for the CPU (and not into an intermediate language, as with Java) then developers are able to get the best performance

How can one use it?

Here best tutorials

https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html

https://www.androidauthority.com/android-ndk-everything-need-know-677642/

https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html