# List all the dependencies used in the android aar library

Tags: android, dependency-management

I am wondering if there is a way to list all the library dependencies in an android library (aar file). We have a library built on Android NDK. I never worked on the library myself but I would like to know all the open source dependencies with the library for open source licensing checks.

Comment: You mean to say `External Libraries` that link to your Android project?

Comment: Yes, the external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding I'm showing screenshots.

**1. Click on Project**

[image: External Libraries used in AS project]

**2. Click on External Libraries**

[image: External Libraries used in AS project]

You can also check your App dependencies by clicking Gradle Tab on the right, and then by double clicking `androidDependencies`

[image: External Libraries used in AS project]

**It's very helpful, when you want to know which Dependency is causing Conflicts in your Project**

[image: External Libraries used in AS project]

**Edit:**

**What is the Android NDK?**

The Android Native Development Kit allows developers to get the most performance out of devices, this can be beneficial for game engines like Unity or Unreal Engine. Because the source code is compiled directly into machine code for the CPU (and not into an intermediate language, as with Java) then developers are able to get the best performance. It is also possible to use other developers’ libraries or your own if there is something that you absolutely need to use.

**How to install and use**

Installing the Android NDK is as easy as going to `Preferences > Android SDK > Android NDK` on OS X, and `File > Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools > NDK` on Windows.

**Disadvantage**

NDK cannot access lots of APIs available in the Android SDK directly, and developing in NDK will always introduce extra complexity into your application.

Read more: [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/), [here](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-ndk-everything-need-know-677642/) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660621/what-is-the-android-native-development-kit-ndk)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This helped. But one question is I use NDK in my project. I dont see this as the dependency. Isn't this a dependency too?

Comment: Edited the answer! :)

Comment: Sorry your edit dont really answer the question. I know what is NDK and how to use it. My question was more why is it not a dependency in the gradle.properties.

Comment: Nevermind. Btw, your comment here is a contradiction to what you already asked in the question. In a way, if you know about `Android NDK`, you shouldn't have asked the question in the first place, that's why I clarified in the comment, please check. Regarding, why it is not a dependency, well I have already answered it. Anyways, nice knowing you. Thanks!