# Android Support for both Kotlin and C (possible duplicate)

Tags: android, c, kotlin

I'm working on a project that needs to hook into another project that is written in C, and it can be used by both Android and iOS.  The project structure looks something like this.

```
├── Android
|   ├── foo1.kt
|   └── foo2.kt
├── iOS
|   ├── foo3.swift
|   └── foo4.swift
├── source
|   ├── foo5.c
|   └── foo6.c
```

The iOS team was able to make wrapper classes that will call the C files (since Swift isn't far removed from C), but I don't know how this would work on Android.  The goal is to call foo() in my Kotlin class and somehow call foo() in the corresponding C library.  By calling this function, it will trigger functionality elsewhere in the library. Is it even possible to bridge the gap between the C language and a JVM language?

example:

> Kotlin class

```
class MyKotlinClass {

     fun fooKotlin() {
         fooC() 
     }
}
```

> Calls C function

```
int fooC() {
    // do stuff in the library that is somewhere else
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Android Native Development Kit (NDK)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660621/what-is-the-android-native-development-kit-ndk)

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/kotlin-app

Comment: That question is vague

Comment: Your original post as written is `Is it even possible to bridge the gap between the C language and a JVM language?` and the answer is yes with the Android NDK as noted in the dup link. I've also linked to an example project for using C with Kotlin on Android. If your post acknowledges that you know about the NDK, then as written the post is too broad. If you can improve your question (or write a new one) as to what the difficulty is (auto-create wrappers?, don't under how JNI works?) but realize that most resources online are still Java/JNI/C not Kotlin/JNI/C. Research Java/JNI, then ask.